# Node JS app on OpenShift gives error 503

Tags: node.js, git, error-handling, openshift

So I created a **NodeJS** app for a college project which monitors page loading speed. In order to record said speed I need people to go to the web application, go to a certain page and hit a button a couple of times.

So I looked up a way to host this app, free of charge, and came up with **OpenShift**.

After figuring out how it all worked I managed to setup an OpenShift git-repository and I am able to push my changes to the server.

However upon visiting my page I kept getting `error 503`. Initially I thought it was a node modules error so I found `npm shrinkwrap` which solved `npm` version issues. The error, is still around.

When I run the app locally, I get no errors whatsoever and all modules are installed correctly. They are also in a `package.json` file (I used `npm install --save` for all my modules, so no manual editing was performed).

These are the first couple of lines from using the `tail`-command and whopping the result into a text file.

```
 ==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log <==
    at Connection.connect (/var/lib/openshift/550db5624382ecf8f400000f/app>root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:109:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/550db5624382ecf8f400000f/approot/runtime/repo/server.js:28:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
```

I also found this:

```
 ==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log <==
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/lib/openshift/550db5624382ecf8f400000f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:135:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/var/lib/openshift/550db5624382ecf8f400000f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (/var/lib/openshift/550db5624382ecf8f400000f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:109:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/550db5624382ecf8f400000f/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:28:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
```

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

Mine did the same when I first pushed to OpenShift.  I think I had to review some references and make some slight changes.  My log on OpenShift indicated that such-and-such file couldn't be found.  Yours might, too, if you review the entire thing.

For example, this is the "after" version of something I edited:

```
        self.app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

I might have had just this before:

```
        self.app.set('views', '/views');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I already have something like that in my server file

`var engine = require("ejs-locals");
app.engine("ejs",engine);
app.set("views",path.join(__dirname,"views"));`

Thanks for trying though :)

Answer (score 0):

Well... you've got...

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

...which suggests that Express couldn't connect to the database.  Maybe you've got dev versus prod credentials going on and the code's trying to use the local credentials, the local database name, the local username, the local server, etc.

I'm using MongoDB (no credentials locally) and have created a /db.js file to store all that.  And then my /server.js selects which variable:

```
if (typeof process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP === "undefined") { mongoose.connect(dbConfig.devurl); } else { mongoose.connect(dbConfig.produrl); }
```

Note the two different variables after dbConfig.varname.

Comment: I'm currently using a MySQL database cartridge and I have a config.json file setup in my nodejs project that uses the same databasename / username and password as the phpMyAdmin interface from OpenShift.
So how could my database be the issue?

Comment: Is the database cartridge part of this nodejs application or is it part of a different OpenShift application?

Comment: @user3054363 Well... "connect ECONNREFUSED" is the error and that looks like a database connection error.  Like MartinB is suggesting, I'm hoping that you just did an "add cartridge" to your other gear to get MySQL going.  On the production system I'm pretty sure there are env variables set.  In my case:  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST, process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT, the default dbName in my case would match my main application alias, and then they issued me 'admin' with an auto-generated password.